# Sorting Grid View using Spinner , XML array, and Custom adapter in android

Tags: android

Friends, I am a new developer in the field of android and I want to develop an application like that it will sort the Gridview by using a spinner, I had applied the XML array for Spinner and Custom adapter also I tried various solution but it didn't work so please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moodel Class for adapter of GridAdapter

```
package braniacs.com.gridupdaterapp;

/**
 * Created by grimReaper on 12/4/2017.
 */

public class GridModel {
    String thingName;

    public String getThingName() {
        return thingName;
    }

    public void setThingName(String thingName) {
        this.thingName = thingName;
    }
}
```

MainActvityCode along adapter in it!

```
package braniacs.com.gridupdaterapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    GridView mGridViewA;
    Spinner mspinnerColony;
    ArrayList<GridModel> ColonyArray;
    String[] ColonyArraySpinnerWali = {"hie", "wasteage", "short", "Lovely", "RUSSIA", "ASIA", "KOREA"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mGridViewA = findViewById(R.id.mgridViewApp);
        mspinnerColony = findViewById(R.id.spnr_colony);
        ColonyArray = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayAdapter mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ColonyArraySpinnerWali);
        mspinnerColony.setAdapter(mArrayAdapter);
        mspinnerColony.setSelection(0);
        mspinnerColony.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                if (i != 0) {
                    GridModel mgRIDmODEL = new GridModel();
                    TextView mTitle = (TextView) view;
                    mgRIDmODEL.setThingName(mTitle.getText().toString());
                    ColonyArray.add(mgRIDmODEL);
                    GridVuCustionAdapter adapter = new GridVuCustionAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                            R.layout.custom_gridvu_design, ColonyArray);
                    mGridViewA.setAdapter(adapter);
                }

            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });


        mGridViewA.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
             // CLICK LISTENER AREA
            }
        });

    }


    public static class GridVuCustionAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<GridModel> {
        LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
        ArrayList<GridModel> objects;
        Context context;
        int resource;


        public GridVuCustionAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull ArrayList<GridModel> objects) {
            super(context, resource, objects);
            mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            this.objects = objects;
            this.context = context;
            this.resource = resource;

        }


        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return objects.size();
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
            convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);

            TextView txtVuTitle = convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_vu_name);
            ImageView imgVuCancel = convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_vu_cancel);
            txtVuTitle.setText(objects.get(position).getThingName());
            return convertView;
        }


    }
}
```

the xml file for custom design for the design is simple here

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_vu_name"
        android:layout_weight="1.7"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:id="@+id/img_vu_cancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_dialog" />
</LinearLayout>
```

the xml file is here for the activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="braniacs.com.gridupdaterapp.MainActivity">

    <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/mgridViewApp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.498" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spnr_colony"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="45dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```